# how to get the value of a variable member of one class to another

Tags: c++, qt

One class has a combo box where a user has to select a number from it. The value is then assigned to a variable and since combo box items are texts, the variable holding the number (in other words,text) the user selected is converted to integer value using 'toInt()' and assigned to an integer variable in the same class. Now, a different class has to have access to the other class's integer variable (i.e. the number the user selected) so that based on it's value, the same number of widgets are displayed to the user. When i select the number from the combo box and hit the pushbutton, nothing is diplayed. I expect the same number i selected from the combo box to dsiplay as line edits.

The code;

combobox.h

```
#ifndef COMBOBOX_H
#define COMBOBOX_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

class ComboBox : public QDialog {
public:
    ComboBox();
    ~ComboBox();

private slots:
    void on_go_button_clicked();

private:
    QComboBox *comboBox;

public:
    QPushButton *go;
    int textToInt;
};

#endif // COMBOBOX_H
```

lineeditwidgets.h

```
#ifndef LINEEDITWIDGETS_H
#define LINEEDITWIDGETS_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include "combobox.h"

class LineEditWidgets : public QDialog {
public:
    LineEditWidgets();
    LineEditWidgets(ComboBox*);      //edited
    ~LineEditWidgets();

private:
    QLineEdit *lineEdit;

    //object created so member of class 'ComboBox' can be accessed
    ComboBox *take;
};

#endif // LINEEDITWIDGETS_H
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QStackedWidget>

#include "lineeditwidgets.h"
#include "combobox.h"

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void go_button_clicked();

private:
    QStackedWidget *pages;

    ComboBox *comboBoxWindow;
    LineEditWidgets *lineEditWindow;

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

combobox.cpp

```
#include <QtGui>
#include "combobox.h"

ComboBox::ComboBox() {
    comboBox = new QComboBox;
    QStringList items;
    items << "1" << "2" << "3" << "4" << "5";
    comboBox->addItems(items);

    go = new QPushButton("Go");

    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(comboBox);
    layout->addWidget(go);

    setLayout(layout);

    /*i get 'No such slot QDialog::on_go_button_clicked()' even though this 
      function was declared as a slot in the header file*/
    connect(go, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(on_go_button_clicked()));
}

/*the number selected from combobox is converted to integer here. I can't 
  seem to understand how 'toInt()' works, i thought it was like 
  'stringstream()' */
void ComboBox::on_go_button_clicked() {
    QString text;
    comboBox->currentTextChanged(text);
    QString getCurrentText = comboBox->currentText();
    textToInt = getCurrentText.toInt();
}

ComboBox::~ComboBox() {

}
```

lineeditwidgets.cpp

```
#include <QtGui>
#include "lineeditwidgets.h"

LineEditWidgets::LineEditWidgets(ComboBox* comboBoxWin) {  //edited
    /*member of 'ComboBox' class is accessed here and assigned to int 
      variable. I thought it's supposed to be holding the number the user 
      selected by now*/        
    /*take = new ComboBox;*/           //edited
      take = comboBoxWin;              //edited

    int numb = take->textToInt;

    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;

    for (int i = 0; i < numb; i++) {
        lineEdit = new QLineEdit;
        layout->addWidget(lineEdit);
    }

    setLayout(layout);
}

LineEditWidgets::~LineEditWidgets(){

}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <ui_mainwindow.h>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent){
    comboBoxWindow = new ComboBox;
    /*lineEditWindow = new LineEditWidgets;*/     //edited
     lineEditWindow = new LineEditWidgets(comboBoxWindow);  //edited

    pages = new QStackedWidget;
    pages->insertWidget(1, comboBoxWindow);
    pages->insertWidget(2, lineEditWindow);
    pages->setCurrentWidget(comboBoxWindow);

    setCentralWidget(pages);

    connect(comboBoxWindow->go, SIGNAL(clicked()), this,  
    SLOT(go_button_clicked()));
}

void MainWindow::go_button_clicked() {
    pages->setCurrentWidget(lineEditWindow);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {

}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: "Can't get it to work" is not a valid question or a description. What's the problem? Code doesn't compile? Show the error message. You're getting incorrect results? Explain what results you're getting, what results you were expecting to get, and what is the difference.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik nothing is displayed.  i have updated my question.

Comment: Below 3 ways can be used depending on the access specifier.

 1. If it can be kept `public` then you can save the user entered variable in a global variable and and use `extern` in other files to get access to it. You can also use inheritance concept to achieve this.
 2. If it is `protected` you can access it through derived class and then share it with external world using some global variables as mentioned above.
 3. If it is a `private` data then the same can be shared to other classes by making use of friend functions and from there it can be assigned to a global variable.

Comment: @yanivx i was expecting the answer to be fixed inside the part of my code where needed. I tried the 'extern' though, by making the variable that converts the number selected by the user to 'int' but it didn't work.

Comment: @0saberima hope you tried extern on a global variable if not then extern won't work

Comment: The best way is to let combo box emit a signal and let line edit receive it.

Comment: @yanivx how can i make a variable member of a class global ?

Comment: @user3528438 i'd like an example by code or fixing it in the part of my code where i went wrong, please!

Comment: The max you can do is make your variable as public and otherway would be to store the value of this variable in a global variable as follows

int x_global// global 

class {
  private:
  int x;
  void somefunc()
  {
      x_global = convert string to int and save it in global variable
   }
};

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that there are two separate instances of `ComboBox`. One is created in MainWindow - `comboBoxWindow = new ComboBox;` and the other one is created in LineEditWidgets - `take = new ComboBox;`

You should consider passing the ComboBox instance - `comboBoxWindow` to LineEditWidgets instance `lineEditWindow` in the constructor of `MainWindow`and the `lineEditWindow` must save the passed instance of `ComboBox` to the `ComboBox` pointer - `take`.

Comment: Confused! If you can please fix the part of my code where i went wrong and commenting it so i understand your fix, i'll appreciate it

Comment: yea i've seen it, but i get  'No such slot QDialog::on_go_button_clicked()' warning when i run the code, making it behave the same way it behaved before your edit. i.e. not showing the line edits after i've selected the number and hit the push button

Comment: plus i want to know if 'toInt()' performs the same function as 'stringstream()' ?

Comment: You seem to be missing `Q_OBJECT` in the `ComboBox ` class. Run qmake after adding `Q_OBJECT`

Comment: i applied it and the warning is gone. But after hitting the button, nothing still shows. So i'm thinking it's `toInt()` causing the problem. Is it the same as `stringstream()` ?